# How to compose validation, disjunction and futures properly

Tags: scala, scalaz, monad-transformers

I have to call 2 functions, the first one is returning a \/[String, Int], the other one is returning a Future[Int].

I need to accumulate the validation of this 2 function calls.

Here is my attempt :

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scalaz._, Scalaz._, Validation._

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def positive(x: Int): \/[String,Int] = if(x<0) "ko".left else x.right

def inc(x: Int): Future[Int] = if (x >5) Future.successful(x +1) else Future.failed(new Exception("failed"))                                              

def eval(x:Int, y:Int): Future[Validation[String, (Int, Int)]] = for {
  v1 <- Future.successful(positive(x).validation)
  v2 <- inc(y).map(x => success(x)).recover{case ex: Exception => failure(ex.getMessage)}
} yield ((v1 |@| v2){(_,_)})
```

) Is there a simpler way to do this, to avoid manual biding of future errors to success/failure?

2) I'd like to use ValidationNel to accumulate error messages (right now I retrieve messages like "Failure(kofailed)" with just a concatenation of the 2 messages) but I don't know if it's possible to get a ValidationNel from a \/ type.

Comment: You can use `toValidationNel` and `failureNel` for (2): `positive(x).validation.toValidationNel`, `success(x).toValidationNel` and `failureNel(ex.getMessage)`.

Comment: @PeterNeyens thanks it's better like this! :)